# react-bootstrap justify-content-end not being recognized when in desktop resolution, only when in mobile

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to mix the alignment of `<Nav>` items:

- In desktop resolution, they should be `justify-content-end`.
- In mobile resolution, they should be `fill`.

I can not get any alignment working in the desktop resolution, only in the mobile resolution.

No matter what I put the desktop resolution stays left aligned:
[image]

The mobile resolution is exactly how I want it:
[image]

**So the questions are how can I mix the two and what am I doing wrong in my implementation?**

```
// parent Navigation.tsx
// Bootstrap imports
import { Container, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

// Component imports
import NavigationItems from './NavigationItems';

// Import data
import data from '../../data/data.json';

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect sticky='top' expand='lg'>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand>{data.navbar.navBrand}</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' />
        <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav' className='justify-content-end'>
          <NavigationItems {...data.navbar.navItems} />
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

```
// child NavigationItems.tsx
// Bootstrap imports
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => (
  <Nav fill className='me-auto'>
    { 
      Object.entries(props).map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Nav.Item key={index}>
            <Nav.Link href={item[1].href}>{item[1].name}</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
        )
      })
    }
  </Nav>
);

export default NavigationItems;
```

The `<Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav' className='justify-content-end'>` came from the documentation example [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#text-and-non-nav-links).

I've tried `<Nav className='me-auto justify-content-end'>` but that only affects the alignment when in the mobile resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with that satisfies what I was after:

```
// Navigation.tsx

// Bootstrap imports
import { Container, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

// Component imports
import NavigationItems from './NavigationItems';

// Declare types
type Navigation = {
  navBrand: {
    value: string,
    href: string,
  },
  navItems: {
    value: string,
    href: string
  }[]
}

// Component for the navbar element
const Navigation = (props: Navigation): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect sticky='top' expand='lg' bg='white'>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href={props.navBrand.href}>{props.navBrand.value}</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
        <Navbar.Collapse className='justify-content-end'>
          <NavigationItems {...props.navItems} />
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

```
// NavigationItems.tsx

// Bootstrap imports
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

// Declare types
type NavigationItems = {
  value: string,
  href: string
}[]

// Component for the navbar items
const NavigationItems = (props: NavigationItems): JSX.Element => (
  <Nav fill>
    { 
      Object.entries(props).map((navItem, i) => {
        return (
          <Nav.Item key={i}>
            <Nav.Link href={navItem[1].href}>{navItem[1].value}</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
        )
      })
    }
  </Nav>
);

export default NavigationItems;
```

[image]
[image]